# Story about a tree that can grant wishes but takes your soul

Tags: story-identification

I read this book about four to five years ago. It had an image of a twisted tree on the front, with a sort of cobalt blue background. I think there may be a moon behind the tree, but I don't know.

What I remember:

- The main characters are about a girl and her younger brother (I don't remember their names)
- The brother has a leg that either got injured or something happened to it (he had a crutch or a cane)
- They go to a house with a giant tree beside it
- The family that owns the house all have red hair
- The parents of the main characters died in a boating accident (hurricane [?])
- The tree grants wishes if you walk to a part where the tree melds with the house, and there is a hole - objects appear in the hole; Your heart's deepest desire is made into physical form
- The watchman takes a silvery substance from you at night once you wish
- The sister's hair becomes darker as she wishes for letters from her parents
- The family and the main characters escape but the house and the tree burn down

Does anyone know the name of this book?

It is not *Wishtree*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*The Night Gardener*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18405537.The_Night_Gardener) by Jonathan Auxier

[image: Front cover of The Night Gardener]

> The Night Gardener follows two abandoned Irish siblings who travel to work as servants at a creepy, crumbling English manor house. But the house and its family are not quite what they seem. Soon the children are confronted by a mysterious spectre and an ancient curse that threatens their very lives. With Auxier’s exquisite command of language, The Night Gardener is a mesmerizing read and a classic in the making.

It came up in [this Goodreads query](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/20150571-solved-ya-story-of-two-siblings-and-a-tree-that-grants-bad-wishes-s), which I found by searching for `site:goodreads.com tree "grants wishes" "red hair"`

> This story is about two siblings; an older sister and a younger brother who is crippled. They are poor and decide to go and work as servants to a rich family, however something seems off. The family is strange and acts weird. Their mistress advises the protagonist (the girl) to never enter a specific room.
>
> Spoilers present from henceforth;
>
> Inside that room is something (I forgot what) that is related to the large tree which the house is connected too. However this isn't a normal tree, it grants wishes but anyone who uses its powers realizes that its a curse.
>
> For example the husband of the mistress is in financial debt so he asks the tree for money which it provides but the debt never goes away and he is forced to keep using the trees money. One of their children gets candy from the tree. The protagonist acquires letters from her mother which she knows aren't real. And her brother gets a can at the end of the book (which decides not to use) that would allow his broken leg to be perfect for a short amount of time.
>
> Another important person in the book (I forgot his name I don't even think he had a name) is the gardener who overlooks the tree gives it water and is try's to kill the family and the protagonist.

Comment: You can check out a copy at https://archive.org/details/nightgardener0000auxi_k6o8 (there's at least one other copy available if this one is already checked out).